# Why doesn't this simple JavaScript work in FireFox or Chrome?

Tags: javascript, function, dom-events

Why does this simple code not work in Firefox and Chrome but it works on IE? What's wrong with this script? I just want to find a way too get selected checkbox text (or label) and use it a `$_post` on another page.

```
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function ReadCheckbox()
{
    var temp = '';
    var radio;
    var popupTag ;

    for (var i=1 ; i<5 ; i++) {
        radio = document.getElementById('chk'+i);

        if(radio.checked == true){temp += radio.value}
    }

      document.getElementById('aaaa').value = temp;

}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<label>What is your Site Address ?</label><br/>
<label>NetNic.ir</label><input id="chk1" type="checkbox" value="NetNic.ir" />
<label>SarirWeb.Com</label><input id="chk2" type="checkbox" value="SarirWeb.Com"/>
<label>LearnCD.ir</label><input id="chk3" type="checkbox" value="LearnCD.ir"/> 
<label>AnimLand.ir</label><input id="chk4" type="checkbox" value="AnimLand.ir"/> 
<br />
<br/>
<textarea rows="2" name="aaaa" cols="20"></textarea>
<input type="button" onclick="ReadCheckbox()" value="ثبت" style="height:32px; width:83px;"/>
```

Comment: Because IE thinks **name** and **id** are the same thing, other browsers don't. Give the textarea an ID of 'aaaa'.

Answer (score 0):

`name="aaaa"` is not an id. So `getElementById('aaaa')` will not find it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<textarea rows="2" name="aaaa" id="aaaa" cols="20"></textarea>
```